# Moment js: Keep UTC date/time in UTC only

Tags: javascript, momentjs, utc

```
date = moment(startDate).startOf('day');

date.format('2019-01-01't)
```

Above code is converting UTC date to local date. How do i keep UTC date UTC?

startDate is a datetime string in iso format

Comment: my date is already in utc format. Dont want to convert to utc.

Comment: moment(date, 'MM-DD-YYYY').utc().format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm"), is this what you want?

Comment: @Alexis i guess he gets a utc value but after the format he converts it to non utc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [moment docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/):

> By default, moment parses and displays in local time.
>
> If you want to parse or display a moment in UTC, you can use
>   `moment.utc()` instead of `moment()`.

So even though your datestring is UTC and moment is correctly parsing the date, it still displays the output in local time unless you use `moment.utc()`. To display in utc:

```js
const s = '2019-03-08T14:59:40Z';
const date = moment.utc(s).startOf('day').format();
console.log(date);
// 2019-03-08T00:00:00Z
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```